# How to get minus and plus in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, system

i have 2 tables `p_budget` and `p_services`

`p_budget` contains

```
id|project_name|budget|source
```

the other table `p_services`

```
id|user|project_name|sdo|transpo|total
```

I want a php that will add the `p_services` and minus the budget in `p_budget`.

i hope you can help me with my project :(

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Help with the query (the join, maybe?) or an entire script? What do you have so far?

Comment: the entire scipt. can you give me an example? i want the project_name will minus the budget depends on the table p_services

Comment: This isn't the place to have people do your work. Happy to help, but at a minimum you should post as far as you can get. Some sort of code is better than no code, even if it's way off base.

Comment: yes i know but i dont know how to start. thank you for your reply

Comment: If the below doesn't get you going, I'd recommend Tizag. There's likely something better out there now, but I found it really digestible when I first got started: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are saying, you want a variable taken out of table 1, and a variable from table 2 subtracted from it, right? You have to learn how to do this yourself so you can manipulate tables, but I will provide an example.

```
//This should start your code, it connects to the db and table.
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "databasename");
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "databasename") or die(mysqli_error());

//This gets a single row from the table and lays it out
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM p_budget WHERE ID=$IDthatyouarecurrentlyusing");

//Then it pulls one item on the table row out, in this case budget.
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$budget = $row['budget'];
```

Now, if you understand that, you can replicate it for the other table, and then:

```
$profit = $budget - $services;
echo $profit;
```

Comment: why do you have a second `mysqli_connect()`?

Comment: And for future reference, include code and do more research on yourself. I had lots of trouble grasping concepts like this a month ago. Read the PHP Manual, it's better than any tutorial, but also more pedantic. If you're going to be a programmer, you must be able to stand things that are somewhat pedantic.

Comment: I copied most of it directly from a code I have, and edited some things. I think I included the second one in order to ensure that the error message worked, though looking back I don't think it's necessary. Not really hurting anything either though. Don't fix it if it isn't broken?

Comment: There is no good reason to have redundant, unused code. It would be best to fix it, before it is broken. Also, you should use [`mysqli_connect_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php), not `mysqli_error()` on your connection.